# Read bulk data from using jdbc batch

Tags: performance, jdbc, batch-processing, bulkinsert

I have a scenario to read data from data base, modify and again I need to update the database. Data in the database is more than 1 lac.

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
    throws SQLException {

Statement stmt = null;
String query = "SELECT ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM BANK.ACCOUNT";
String updateUuery = "UPDATE BANK.ACCOUNT ACCOUNT_NUMBER=? WHERE ID=?";

try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateUuery);
    stmt.setFetchSize(25);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("ID");
        String accountNumber = rs.getString("ACCOUNT_NUMBER");
        String decrypt=decryptString(accountNumber);
        String encrypt=encryptString(decrypt);
        ps.setString(1,encrypt);
        ps.setInt(2,supplierID);
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException e) {
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) {
        stmt.close();
    }
}}public static String encryptString(String encryptString){ //algorithm to encrypt
return "encryptedString";
```

}

Currently I am using pure JDBC to read and update using batch.

My questions are

1. To give better performance, how to read bulk data and update.
2. If i commit the data 1 lac records should commit.If anything fails 1 lac records roll back(in single transaction).

   enter code here

Comment: I think it's not clear at all what you are trying to do, or what your question actually is. Please also share with us (code?) how you have designed the algorithm now and what you think needs improvement.

Comment: added code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380523/connection-pool-batch-retrieval-and-update-using-jdbc